# StreamBuilder call Firestore twice after initialization

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a FireStore collection with 5 documents, and I have 2 duplicate screens (in bottom navigation bar) that listen to this collection changes with StreamBuilder.. It's a demo app for try the FireStore (See code below).

When I'm change (manually) 1 document in the FireStore so the StreamBuilder run Twice, **and instead of get 10 read actions I got 20!** and that can affect my firebase costs..

I see a lot of answers about this Stream behavior that run twice, but all of them is about the **Initialization** of the stream, and in my case is after the **Initialization**

How can I avoid this behavior?

**First screen**

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Stream<List<String>> chatStream = Api.getChat();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: chatStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container();
          }
          if (snapshot.data == null ) {
            return Text('Data null');
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Text(snapshot.data[i]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Second screen**

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Stream<List<String>> chatStream = Api.getChat();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: chatStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container();
          }
          if (snapshot.data == null ) {
            return Text('Data null');
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Text(snapshot.data[i]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The listener**

```
class Api {
  static final CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat');

  static Stream<List<String>> getChat() {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> result = users.snapshots();
    final Stream<List<String>> chat = result.map((event) => event.docs.map((e) {
          return (e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['text'].toString();
        }).toList());
    return chat;
  }
}
```

**The result in Firebase dashboard**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zYdy.png)

Comment: First and second screen seem to be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StatelessWidget`s get re-created every time their parents' build() is called again. It can be called again and again for various reasons.

Every time `FirstScreen` is re-created, `Api.getChat();` is called one more time, resulting in more Firebase reads. You don't want that.

Instead you want to make these `StatefulWidget`s and call `Api.getChat();` in `initState` once. That will ensure that no extra Firestore reads would happen.

```
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  final Stream<List<String>> chatStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chatStream = Api.getChat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: chatStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container();
          }
          if (snapshot.data == null ) {
            return Text('Data null');
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Text(snapshot.data[i]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You could also keep it in State the way you had before, but it's a bit more elegant the other way. It is a reminder in case it is something that you may need to dispose of in `dispose()`.

```
  final Stream<List<String>> chatStream = Api.getChat();
```